# Trouble slicing based on function +1

Tags: python, find, slicers

I am trying to search `c_item_number_one = (r'12" Pipe SA-106 GR. B SCH 40 WALL smls'.upper())` for `"` to pull both it and all information in front of it. i.e. I want `12"`

I thought I could just search for what position `"` is in...

```
def find_nps_via_comma_item_one():
    nps = '"'
    print(c_item_number_one.find(nps))
find_nps_via_comma_item_one()
```

[Image showing above function results in 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBJLi.png)
and then slice everything off after it

```
c_item_number_one = (r'12" Pipe SA-106 GR. B SCH 40 WALL smls'.upper())

def find_nps_via_comma_item_one():
    nps = '"'
    print(c_item_number_one.find(nps))
find_nps_via_comma_item_one()

item_one_nps = slice(3)
print(c_item_number_one[item_one_nps])
```

***Issue:*** It is returning an error

```
print(c_item_number_one[item_one_nps])

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

How can I turn the results of my function into an integer? I've tried changing `print(c_item_number_one.find(nps))` to `return(c_item_number_one.find(nps))` but then it stopped giving a value entirely.

Lastly, the slice portion does not produce the full answer I am looking for `12"`. Even if I enter the value produced by the function `2`

```
item_one_nps = slice(2)
print(c_item_number_one[item_one_nps])
```

It only gives me `12`. I need to `+1` the function results.

Comment: Your `find_nps_via_comma_item_one` isn't returning anything, so you get `None`.

Comment: @MarkRansom It returns 2 in JupyterLab. I added a sniptit link above to show the results.

Comment: Printing something is *not* the same as returning something.  Your function doesn't have a `return` statement in it.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for the suggestions. That 2nd comment eventually led me to realize I was on the right track originally but forgot to add my ```()``` to function when slicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print statement prints a value to the console whereas a return returns a value where the function is call.

In your code you are not storing the value but just printing it to the console even when you used return instead of print you weren't making use of the returned value.

`1` is being added to the slice since while slicing python excludes the stop index so to include the stop index you add `1`

```
c_item_number_one = (r'12" Pipe SA-106 GR. B SCH 40 WALL smls'.upper())

def find_nps_via_comma_item_one():
    nps = '"'
    return(c_item_number_one.find(nps))

item_one_nps = slice(find_nps_via_comma_item_one()+1)
print(c_item_number_one[item_one_nps])
```

The following code is more verbose.

```
c_item_number_one = (r'12" Pipe SA-106 GR. B SCH 40 WALL smls'.upper())

def find_nps_via_comma_item_one():
    nps = '"'
    return(c_item_number_one.find(nps))

index = find_nps_via_comma_item_one()

item_one_nps = slice(index+1)
print(c_item_number_one[item_one_nps])
```

Comment: Thanks snowmanstark! I found a slightly different solution. My main issue was that I forgot to include my ```()``` on my function in ```slice(find_nps_via_comma_item_one())```.


```def find_nps_via_comma_item_one():
    nps = '"'
    return((c_item_number_one.find(nps))+1)
find_nps_via_comma_item_one()

item_one_nps = slice(find_nps_via_comma_item_one())
print(c_item_number_one[item_one_nps])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
sep_char = "\"" 
c_item_number_one.split(sep_char)[0] + sep_char
```

Comment: This is a more straight forward method. I was using the split method originally but never crossed my mind to solve it this way....